How to type hint a function that parallelize multiple functions and return their results?
Link to mypy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=a4da5db5bfbdf1e6bddce442286cc843
More often than not, I find myself connecting to multiple APIs and then collecting the results. Requests to multiple APIs can be made in parallel.
from typing import Dict, List, TypeVar, Callable, Tuple, overload
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_airflow() -> str:
    return "a"
def get_prometheus() -> Dict[str, str]:
    return {"b": "c"}
def get_zabbix() -> List[str]:
    return ["d", "e"]

adata = get_airflow()
pdata = get_prometheus()
zdata = get_zabbix()

I can parallelize it using ThreadPoolExecutor:
exe = ThreadPoolExecutor()
arr = [
     exe.submit(get_airflow),
     exe.submit(get_prometheus),
     exe.submit(get_zabbix),
]
adata = arr[0].result()
pdata = arr[1].result()
zdata = arr[2].result()

However, this design requires that I keep a separate list of submits and a separate list of variable assignments, and I have to keep those lists in sync and don't mix. It also loses any typing information. Is there a way I could write it better? Something along:
adata, pdata, zdata = paralelize(get_airflow, get_prometheus, get_zabbix)

How to write such a function to preserve typing information? I tried the following, but I do not understand how to preserve types or construct a tuple with a dynamic number of elements:
T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')
T3 = TypeVar('T3')
@overload
def parallelize(a: Callable[[], T1]) -> Tuple[T1]: ...
@overload
def parallelize(a: Callable[[], T1], b: Callable[[], T2]) -> Tuple[T1, T2]: ...
@overload
def parallelize(a: Callable[[], T1], b: Callable[[], T2], c: Callable[[], T3]) -> Tuple[T1, T2, T3]: ...
def parallelize(*cbs: Callable[[], Any]) -> Tuple[Any]:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        return (x.result() for x in [exe.submit(cb) for cb in cbs])

How to write such a function to preserve typing information? Is it possible using standard functions, like futures.concurrent.wait(..)[0]? Is there a better way to do it?

side note: the mypy link has a spelling-typo when calling parallelize and Any is missing in the import

Since parallelize can be called with an arbitrary set of functions, what's the point of trying to specify the types? Are you just looking for a way to say that the types of the results are correlated with the types of the arguments?

If that's your issue, it has little to do with multithreading. You'd have the same problem if you were calling the functions normally.

I think yes, but I didn't want to ask xy question, so i gave the context. And yes, i also agree. I am looking for a way to specify that the tuple return value is the return types from arguments functions.

It is currently not possible to apply a transformation on each element of a TypeVarTuple.
However, there are recent discussions and a PEP draft on this very topic, which propose the following syntaxes:
def parallelize[*Ts](*args: *Callable[[], Ts]) -> tuple[*Ts]:
    ...

def paralellize[*Ts](*args: Map[Callable[[], T], Ts]) -> tuple[*Ts]:
    ...

These are non-concrete and have yet to be supported by any type checkers.
